# Ammend 'w' behavior - ignore operators and brackets - '(', '[' '{', '*', '+', '='

Tags: cursor-motions, vi-words

As the title says. Is it possible?

#### Steps to reproduce:

Type in `sample(text)` and put the cursor on the first character then press `w`.

#### Expected behavior:

Cursor moves to beginning of next word - `text`

[image]

#### Current (and default) behavior:

The cursor moves to the first brace.

[image]

---

The Same thing occurs when there is for example `aaa * bbb` - cursor moves to `*` first.

I tried manipulating `iskeyword` but without success.

Is there a way to tell Vim to ignore those operator and braces characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible?

Anything is possible with some scripting:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>w :call search('\<\w', 'W')<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>e :call search('\w\>', 'W')<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>b :call search('\<\w', 'bW')<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>gE :call search('\w\>', 'bW')<cr>
```

It's not possible to change this behavior with `iskeyword`, however.  Here's what `:h word` says:

> A word consists of a sequence of letters, digits and underscores, or a
>     sequence of other non-blank characters, separated with white space (spaces,
>     tabs, ).  This can be changed with the 'iskeyword' option.  An empty line
>     is also considered to be a word.

That is, a word motion is an *alternating* keyword or non-keyword sequence, that may be separated by whitespace.  A `word` *motion* should not be confused with a word *pattern* (`\w` which only includes `0-9A-Za-z_`).

This illustrates where the cursor jumps when you press `w`:

```
sample(text) { body }
^     ^^   ^ ^ ^    ^
```

Setting `iskeyword+=(` would give you these cursor jump positions:

```
sample(text) { body }
^          ^ ^ ^    ^
```

This is because `sample(text` is now considered a keyword.

This can be made clearer by using `iskeyword=x` to simplify your notion of a word motion:

```
xxxx xxxx xxabcxx def hijxxxlmn
^    ^    ^ ^  ^  ^   ^  ^  ^
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand the frustration, though there are other ways around it which might be better to use since you could find yourself using vim on a server or other environment that doesn't have your customized command changes (and accompanying muscle memory).

In your specific example, you could do `f t` to jump directly to the start of `text`.